# nodejs/expressjs canned rest api not responding

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

I'm using canned to mock a restful api.

It is not working

```
var canned = require('canned'):
var opts = {cors: true, ... }
can = canned('.', opts)
http.createServer(can).listen(5000)
```

I put the index.get.json in './books'

When i try to request data through rest client or browser

http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/books/?name=alice

It responds in the console

`request: get api/books/?name=alice not found`

I tried to remove 'api' but no hope.

index.get.json looks like this:

```
[{"name":"alice", .... }, .... ]
```

Comment: Just tried it and it works just fine. I have my main.js file in `/srv/www/main.js` and index.get.json in `/srv/www/books/index.get.json` and the address is `127.0.0.1:5000/api/books/?name=alice`

Comment: which version are you using ? @Molda

Comment: I used `npm install canned` so whatever the version was 2 days ago. I deleted the test already so don't know really